# Disable hosts file in docker container

Tags: networking, docker

Is it possible to have a docker container running locally to not use the hosts `/etc/hosts` file for dns resolution?

For instance, on my local `/etc/hosts` file I could set `127.0.0.1 stackoverflow.com`, but within my docker container **stackoverflow.com** would resolve to the **actual ip**.

Answer (score 3):

You’ll find the network configuration inside the container is identical to the host only when running container with option `--network=host`.

If you run container without -`-network` option, the Docker daemon connects containers to default `bridge` network. Containers in this default network are able to communicate with each other using IP addresses.

List docker networks with

```
docker network ls
```

and you can inspect them by

`docker network inspect bridge`  (last parameter is network name)

Look at [Docker container networking](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/) for more details.

Comment: thanks for the tips. I saw that network flag in the docs and wasn't using it so I was a little confused, but I'm using docker-compose so that would obviously impact that. Those commands you specified though look promising, thanks again.

Comment: By default Compose (version 2) sets up a single network for your app. Each container for a service joins the default network and is both reachable by other containers on that network, and discoverable by them at a hostname identical to the container name.When you run docker-compose up a network called myapp_default is created. Run "docker network inspect mypp_default" to check what kind of docker network it is. You can also change the settings of the app-wide default network by defining an entry under networks named default. See https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

Comment: I started up the image using `docker run -it --network=bridge ${container_id} /bin/bash` and was still resolving addresses via the hosts host file it seemed.  (I know I don't have to specify the bridge as the network, but just wanted to be clear it wasn't using the host network).  I'm using docker for mac btw in case that matters. Is this expected?

Comment: Docker for mac has different networking, but I don't know it, so I can't help you in depth. You can try calling docker run with --add-host option, but I'm not sure it updates container /etc/hosts only in docker for mac.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it.

> By default, a container inherits the DNS settings of the host, as defined in the /etc/resolv.conf configuration file. Containers that use the default bridge network get a copy of this file

Solution:

```
docker run --dns <your dns address, different from the host's ip>
```

reference:[Docker container networking](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/)